# What are the parts of a derivative called?

Tags: calculus, derivatives, terminology

An integral consists of an integrand and a variable of integration.  What are the two parts of a derivative called?

E.g., in
$$\frac{df(x,y)}{dx},$$
what is $f(x,y)$ called, and what is $x$ called?

Comment: Usually, there are also integration limits. Define the "two parts of a derivative" mathematically, please, that's more important than calling them names.

Comment: I have never seen the equivalent of "integrand" for derivatives. Should be "differentiand", but it sounds weird. On the other hand, "differentiation variable" sounds normal.